# Vichuploader issue only on production environment

Tags: php, symfony-2.8

I have implemented VichUploaderBundle on my website, and everything is working fine on my local environment, but after uploading the updates on the server, the prod environment on the server side is returning:

> HTTP ERROR 500

The dev environment on the server side is returning the following:

> ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 33:
>   Attempted to load class "VichUploaderBundle" from namespace "Vich\UploaderBundle".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Which is confusing since I do have the right "use" statement in my entity. Here is my entity code:

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
/**
 * User
 *
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your lastname.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The lastname is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The lastname is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your firstname.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The firstname is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The firstname is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your phone.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=8,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The phone value is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The phone value is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $phone;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="users_images", fileNameProperty="userImageName")
     * @var File
     */
    private $userImageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    private $userImageName;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MainBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="integer", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $amount;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $updatedAt;


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->date = new \Datetime();
        $this->types = new ArrayCollection();

        $random = intval( "0" . rand(1,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) );
        $this->code = $random;
    }

    /*
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function updateDate()
    {
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \Datetime());
    }

     /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set phone
     *
     * @param string $phone
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phone
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * Set details
     *
     * @param string $details
     * @return User
     */
    public function setDetails($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get details
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDetails()
    {
        return $this->details;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $email = is_null($email) ? '' : $email;
        parent::setEmail($email);
        $this->setUsername($email);

        return $this;
    }

    public function setEmailCanonical($emailCanonical)
    {
        $this->emailCanonical = $emailCanonical;
        $this->usernameCanonical = $emailCanonical;
    }

    /**
     * Get types
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     * @return User
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     *
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return User
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param \MainBundle\Entity\Image $image
     * @return User
     */
    public function setImage(\MainBundle\Entity\Image $image = null)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return \MainBundle\Entity\Image
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastName
     *
     * @param string $lastName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Set code
     *
     * @param integer $code
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get code
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * Set amount
     *
     * @param float $amount
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setAmount($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get amount
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    /**
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile | null $userImageFile
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUserImageFile(File $userImageFile = null)
    {
        $this->userImageFile = $userImageFile;

        // VERY IMPORTANT:
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using Doctrine,
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        if ($userImageFile) {
            // if 'updatedAt' is not defined in your entity, use another property
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return File|null
     */
    public function getUserImageFile()
    {
        return $this->userImageFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $productName
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUserImageName($userImageName)
    {
        $this->userImageName = $userImageName;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getUserImageName()
    {
        return $this->userImageName;
    }
}
```

The AppKernel.php code:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function __construct($environment, $debug)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
    }

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new MainBundle\MainBundle(),
            //new Gregwar\ImageBundle\GregwarImageBundle(),
            //new Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\GregwarCaptchaBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
            new \FOS\ElasticaBundle\FOSElasticaBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new UserBundle\UserBundle(),
            new Vich\UploaderBundle\VichUploaderBundle(),
            //new EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\EasyAdminBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'), true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            $bundles[] = new CoreSphere\ConsoleBundle\CoreSphereConsoleBundle();
            //$bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

config.yml code:

```
   service:
        mailer:                 fos_user.mailer.twig_swift

vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        users_images:
            uri_prefix:         '%app.path.users_images%'
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web%app.path.users_images%'
            namer:              vich_uploader.namer_origname
```

Note that I cleared the cache. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: You've already run composer update, I assume? May there  be a problem with your autoloader?

Comment: @Niellles 44 Maybe I should have added VichUploader dependency by using the command line on production environnement instead of just uploading related files. Let me test that.

Comment: Did you upload any other relevant files except the VichUploader directory inside the vendor dir? Let me know how requiring it via CLI on your production server works out for you...

Comment: I couldn't run "composer require vich/uploader-bundle" using command line in prod environment, so I just uploaded everything from my local environment including vich dependency in vendor directory. I uploaded also composer.lock, AppKernel.php, config.yml and all the new src directory

Comment: Note that I was note able to run composer on prod env, so I didn't run "composer update". Maybe I should run it on local env and then upload everything again

Comment: Yeah, get it to work on your local environment first, then you can take care of getting it to production. Run a `composer update` on your local env and get back to me..

Comment: Everything is working fine in my local environment as I explained in the initial post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174454/discussion-between-niellles-and-patrick).